# Prevent caching captcha on AJAX update in node.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, express, captcha

I am using [`node_captcha`](https://github.com/napa3um/node-captcha) module in my express app. I want captcha image to update on click by setting `src` property with jQuery. To prevent caching, I've applied modifications from this [pull request](https://github.com/vodolaz095/node-captcha/commit/c2834ff7e56f479c108b8bf3427006ba97e0ccea) (added `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers). I also added `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});` to my client script. But Firefox and IE still cache the ajax requests and captcha does not update. The last thing that might help is adding some salt to image url like `"/captcha.jpg?"+Math.random()` but this trick does not work with node + express (Cannot GET captcha.jpg?0.5642369743436575).

[Test page on Codepen](http://codepen.io/Juribiyan/pen/bvlzm) (sorry if my server is down). Click on captcha image to update it. It works fine in Chrome.

**UPDATE:** I gave up on updating captcha via AJAX. Since I use Socket.io anyway, I now get captcha via websocket in form of data-url. If you're facing the same problem, you may consider the same :)

Comment: It should do *exactly* the same as turning off caching with `$.ajaxSetup`, but have you tried adding `cache: false` to the options of your ajax call?  Also, try adding a variable name to the querystring, rather than just a random number (rand=xxxxxx), to see if that gets round your node express issue.  Neither of these are solid answers - they're just suggestions to rule out.

Comment: @Archer already tryed that, does not help

Comment: Good to get that out of the way in early comments then, rather than a page full of those things as suggestions ;)  Can you put together a jsfiddle example so we can try it ourselves?  It does sound very odd.

Comment: I've made a test page on codepen, check it out. Hope my server won't crash.

Comment: I know this thread is old but by default GET requests are used which has caching enabled by default. Using a POST request should have solved your problem, as with POST it forces your browser to actually communicate back with the server regardless of whether or not the page is cached. Also, the response is not cached.